# ADB not reconnecting after device restart

Tags: c#, android, automation, adb

I am working on some software that automates Android functions via ADB. One step of the process is restarting the device and then continuing on. I have been able to complete this successfully with 5 other Android devices, however on my Pixel I am not having the same luck.

To check if the device is connected, I run the adb devices command and ensure the device ID is listed and with the "Online" status. This works great for the devices so far, but on the Pixel, when the phone reconnects after the restart it is reading as "offline" and no commands issued to the device work.

Unplugging the phone and plugging back in fixes the issue, changing the USB protocol (just charge, file transfer, camera mode, etc.) will also fix the issue. However, I would like this to be automated and not require any human intervention.

I have noticed that the device also does not appear in Windows until I take one of the above options.

Has anyone else ran into the issue of devices not returning to an ADB-ready state after using ADB to reboot a device? Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Comment: What is the default USB mode selected on your Pixel ? You can check by going to Developer options -> Networking -> "Select USB configuration"

Comment: I set it to File Transfer, but after restart it is back on Just Charging.

edit: It actually appears to be staying on File Transfer (MTP) now but ADB still will not recognize.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you unplug your device, set the default charging option to MTP and plug it back in ?

Comment: Didn't make any difference. I believe I solved the issue. Plugging the Pixel into a USB 3.0 gives the desired behavior. Very odd that there is a difference in behavior between USB2 and USB3 with ADB.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my Pixel device does not work properly on ADB over USB 2.0. Once I switched the phone to be connected to a USB3.0 port, ADB functioned correctly once again.